# how do I write a function for connecting to mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to write a function to connect to mongodb and return a collection object.  I have the following:

```
def getCollection(dbname,collection):
    client = MongoClient()
    data_base = client.dbname
    collObject = data_base.collection
    return collObject
```

When I run:

```
collection = getCollection(client, "hkpr_restore", "agents")
print collection
```

I get:

```
Collection(Database(MongoClient('localhost', 27017), u'dbname'), u'collection')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: count the number of arguments you are passing to your function. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `client.dbname`, the attribute *dbname* is called, meaning you are retrieving the database named *dbname*.

Same applies for `data_base.collection`.

Solution:

```
def getCollection(dbname, collection):
    client = MongoClient()
    data_base = getattr(client, dbname)
    collObject = getattr(data_base, collection)
    return collObject
```

Alternative: you can use dictionary style access:

```
def getCollection(dbname, collection):
    client = MongoClient()
    data_base = client[dbname]
    collObject = data_base[collection]
    return collObject
```